# react-motion - adding this library to rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, react-motion

Have anyone tried adding react-motion to a rails project?
Have not seed any gems for this, but it would be kind of awesome to use it.

What are the steps I have to make to use it?

I have been trying to add all files to vendor/assets/javascrips and requiring them in application.js but the syntax used in those files is new to me.

Answer (score 2):

One simple way to handle this kind of dependencies to the asset pipeline is using rails-assets here are the instructions for react-motion

https://rails-assets.org/#/components/react-motion

Comment: This seems ok, but and as I am trying to implement some of those demos that are included in react-motion's github page I am bumping into dozens of errors that something (a function for example) that I am trying to use is not defined.

Comment: Could you add your application.js and the javascript code that is giving you the errors?